# Saving the result of a PROC MEANS in a work table

Tags: sas

I try to save the output of a `proc means` in a work table but somehow it will only save N, MEAN, MIN, MEAN, STD. I want the percintiles. The output in the result viewer is correct. This is my code:

```
PROC MEANS DATA= My_data p1 p5 p25 p50 p75 p95 p99;
 VAR my_var;
 output out = tst ;
RUN;
```

So I must use the `outpu out` wrong somehow. I can't find the answer running through this https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/240-29.pdf

**How do I save the results from Result Viewer in a work table?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your reference.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
    var age;
    output out=test p1=p1 p5=p5 p25=p25 p50=p50 p75=p75 p95=p95 p99=p99;
run;
```

if you wanna customize the output variable name

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
    var age;
    output out=test p1=name1 p5=name2;
run;
```